# Get name of newly added interface in udev/rules to pass it as a parameter to a shell script

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, udev

I use usb mode_switch to plug in a device which then is initialized as a lte internet stick with an interface with a MAC address.
Once the stick is plugged in I want to call a shell script which does some other logic which needs the interface name.

So far I have the following rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", RUN+="/home/some/interface_test/dosomething.sh '$attr{bInterfaceClass}'"
```

The rule is calling dosomething.sh once I plug in the stick but the interface name is empty.

Is the attribute right? At this place is it even possible to get the interface name?

Comment: I guess the other lines didn't make sense. @meuh thanks for the hint. I somehow got it with %k parameter but due to mode_usb it sometimes moves the interface and gives it a different name?? Total noob here sorry :-)